# How to get trend component and cyclical component in one series by Python hpfilter?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, statsmodels

This is my data:

```
          Year    Z-value
0   1976-01-01   9.170293
1   1977-01-01   9.130933
2   1978-01-01   9.092142
3   1979-01-01   9.179282
4   1980-01-01   9.031123
5   1981-01-01   8.899608
6   1982-01-01   8.533545
7   1983-01-01   8.648138
8   1984-01-01   8.895921
9   1985-01-01   9.035276
10  1986-01-01   8.898070
11  1987-01-01   9.096961
12  1988-01-01   9.267598
13  1989-01-01   9.270736
14  1990-01-01   9.051413
15  1991-01-01   8.798996
16  1992-01-01   8.821594
17  1993-01-01   8.959126
18  1994-01-01   9.226342
19  1995-01-01   9.453473
20  1996-01-01   9.608805
21  1997-01-01   9.939561
22  1998-01-01  10.030579
23  1999-01-01  10.481201
24  2000-01-01  11.027884
25  2001-01-01  11.023259
26  2002-01-01  11.031710
27  2003-01-01  11.101627
28  2004-01-01  11.321485
29  2005-01-01  11.548922
30  2006-01-01  11.394613
31  2007-01-01  11.238485
32  2008-01-01  11.094884
33  2009-01-01  10.289895
34  2010-01-01  10.493154
35  2011-01-01  10.618517
36  2012-01-01  10.455861
37  2013-01-01  10.617282
38  2014-01-01  10.600950
39  2015-01-01  10.194091
40  2016-01-01  10.212243
41  2017-01-01  10.662858
42  2018-01-01  10.750010
```

and this is my code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from scipy.optimize import minimize, show_options
    import requests
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set()
    cycle, trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(z,43)
    plt.plot(trend)
```

How I can get a time trend component and cyclical component from above Z-value? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
cycle, trend = sm.tsa.filters.hpfilter(df['Z-value'], 43)

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'])

ax = plt.subplot()

ax.plot(df['Year'], df['Z-value'], label='Z-Value')
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax2.plot(df['Year'], cycle, ls='--', label='cycle', c='red')
ax2.plot(df['Year'], trend, label='trend', c='green')

plt.legend()
```

[image]